# Django: using a custom upload_to function, it is possible to query manytomanyfields before saving?

Tags: python, django

I wasn't sure how to title this question.

I am building a journal website using Django 1.10. Using the admin interface, it is possible to add publications. Publications come with multiple authors that are ordered using [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). One also uploads PDF files to the publications. I am trying to ensure that the PDF files have consistent and sensible names by using a custom `upload_to` function for the `FileField` as [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload%5Fto). Specifically, I want the names to be `(lastname of the first author) + "_" + (year of publication) + (a letter that depends on the number of previous publications of the same first author that year) + ".pdf"`. For instance, for first author Smith who publishes a paper in 2016, the filename will be `Smith_2016a.pdf`. The second should be `Smith_2016b.pdf` and so on. I got this to work when one edits an existing publication.

However, if one creates a new publication and tries to add a PDF, one gets an `list index out of range` error. This is because the call to `Person.objects.filter(author_of = instance)` results in an empty query because the current object is not yet saved in the database.

My question is: is it possible to get the lastname of the first author of the new publication in some other way? Without this, one cannot determine which letter to add to the year.

Due to the way `manytomanyfield`s with `through` works, one cannot just use `instance.authors[0]` to get the first author:

```
(Pdb) instance.authors
*** ValueError: "<Publication: Test paper (OQSPS)>" needs to have a value for field "publication" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

A workaround is to save the publication first without the PDF, and then edit it and add the PDF. I tested this and it works.

Perhaps one can force a 2-step saving of new publications in the same way that some fields of new `User`s are not editable in the first step. This seems to be possible according to a [6 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700979/in-django-how-do-i-mimic-the-two-step-method-of-adding-users-through-the-admin).

Some relevant code from `models.py`:

```
def custom_filename(instance, filename):
    #determine lastname of first author
    authors = Person.objects.filter(author_of = instance)

    pdb.set_trace()

    #how many papers by this author this year?
    papers = Publication.objects.filter(authors = authors[0])

    #filter to those where he is first author
    papers_firstauthor = []
    for paper in papers:
        #is it the current paper?
        if paper == instance:
            #then dont count it
            continue

        #is it published after the current paper?
        if paper.publication_date > instance.publication_date:
            #then don't count it
            continue

        #get the authors of that paper
        paper_authors = Person.objects.filter(author_of = paper)

        if paper_authors[0] == authors[0]:
            papers_firstauthor.append(paper)

    #choose a letter fitting to the number of previous papers by that author
    letter = string.ascii_lowercase[len(papers_firstauthor)]

    # file will be renamed to
    return '{0}_{1}{2}.pdf'.format(authors[0].lastname, instance.publication_date.year, letter)

#Publications
class Publication(models.Model):
    #mandatory
    journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal, blank=False)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=False, related_name = "author_of", through='AuthorOrder')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    publication_date = models.DateField(default=now, blank=False)
    submission_date = models.DateField(default=now, blank=False)

    #optional
    abstract = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    pdf = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to=custom_filename) #the current PDF file
    sup_mat_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True) #link to supplementary materials
    peerreview_thread_link = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True) #link to peer review thread on the forum
    reviewers = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name = "reviewer_of")
    old_url = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True) #URL on the old wordpress site
    DOI = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    #self
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} ({1})".format(self.title, self.journal.abbreviation)

    #review length
    def review_time(self):
        return self.publication_date - self.submission_date

#AuthorOrder
class AuthorOrder(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```